# all requests to umbraco site redirect to login page

Tags: forms-authentication, umbraco

I just took my local, functioning umbraco installation and copied it over to the testing environment.

Suddenly ALL requests to my umbraco site, meaning css, javascript etc redirect to the login.aspx page. So the website is non-functional, unless you login. If you manage to login using the no-css form, then everything is back to normal.

Web.config says

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="120" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Changing * to ? makes no difference. What could be the matter here? My setup is 2 configuration mirroring IIS7 web servers, looking at a common UNC path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `allow users="?"` to allow anonymous users.

Check also the section membership...
My web.config contains:

```
<membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

You need to:

- Create a login page (like any other ASP.NET site).
- Create records in
  "Members" section (at least one member type, member group and 
  member).
- Define the restricted access on content nodes (menu "Public
  access").

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check permissions setting of your environment, because if you get redirect for all resources, even for static files - usually it is common permissions problem.

```
/install/default.aspx?installStep=validatePermissions 
or for 4.7+ 
/install/?installStep=filepermissions
```

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/files-and-folders/permissions/perform-permissions-check

Answer (score 1):

It can be a issue with file permissions. As a temporary solution try and set all files to "Everyone" - Modify.

Answer (score 1):

All paths are only accessible with authentication, so you have to exclude js and css from authentication in your web.config, e.g.:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="css">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced this also on a test Umbraco site. Discovered it was owing to the files attempting to access being stored on the disk encrypted (using Windows 7 in my test environment).

Fixed by selecting all site files and folders in Explorer, Properties, Advanced (on General tab), uncheck "Encrypt contents to secure data". Resources could then be accessed on the Umbraco without any authentication redirects.